# React Native NOT rendering data from database on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have problem with render data on IOS Simulator. Render is work properly on website, but on IOS I still got stuck on "Loading.." text.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper'
import firebase from 'firebase'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import Background from '../components/Background'
import TopBar from '../components/TopBar'


export default function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  const sampleData = [{id:0, title:"One"}, {id:1, title: "Two"}]

  useEffect(() =>
  {
    const donorsData = [];
    firebase.database()
      .ref("testdb")
      .orderByChild("isDonor")
      .equalTo(true)
      .once("value")
      .then((results) => {
        results.forEach((snapshot) => {
          donorsData.push(snapshot.val());
           });
        setData(donorsData);
      });
  }, [])

  const card = data.length > 0 
  ? data.map(item =>
  {
    return            <Card key={item.uid} style={{ marginBottom: 20, borderRadius: 10, }}>
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    <Text>{item.description}</Text>
    <Image src={item.photo}></Image>
  </Card>
  })
  
      : <Text>Loading...</Text>



  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      
      {card}
      
    </View>
  );
}
```

On website is everything ok [Website Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vw46.png)

But on IOS Simulator I got only Loading

[IOS Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/splxP.png)

I tried a lot of solutions found here, but no one works with this case. I think is probably because iOS doesn't have data? When I put console log at to top of return, I got nothing.

Comment: May I ask that why you will put the `setData()` in `setTimeout()`? It should put inside the `then()` in `firebase.database()`. So the empty array won't insert to state before the fetch is finished.

Comment: I think i need wait for IOS to get data display. So if i make   

useEffect(() =>
  {
    const donorsData = [];
    firebase.database()
      .ref("treninkove_plany")
      .orderByChild("isDonor")
      .equalTo(true)
      .once("value")
      .then((results) => {
        results.forEach((snapshot) => {
          donorsData.push(snapshot.val());
           });
           setData(donorsData);

      });
  }, [])

Status is same :(.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a race condition error. You shouldn't rely on the data being fetched within 1500ms.

If that doesn't work. Make sure your result from firebase is correct.

Maybe something like this?

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const fetchDonorData = () => {
   firebase.database()
      .ref("testdb")
      .orderByChild("isDonor")
      .equalTo(true)
      .once("value")
      .then((results) => {
         console.log({result}) //Make sure the data looks the way you want it
         const mappedResult = results?.map(snapshot => snapshot.val())
         setData(mappedResult)
       })
}

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDonorData()
  }, [])

const renderItem = ({item}) => 
  <Card style={{ marginBottom: 20, borderRadius: 10, }}>
    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
    <Text>{item.description}</Text>
    <Image src={item.photo}></Image>
  </Card>

return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
       data={data}
       renderItem={renderItem}
       keyExtractor={({item}) => item.uid}
       ListEmptyComponent={<Text>Loading...</Text>}
       />
    </View>
)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Understand what you mean, but whatever i do i got 

Unhandled Promise Rejection: TypeError: results.map is not a function. (In 'results.map(function (snapshot) {
        return snapshot.val();
      })', 'results.map' is undefined).

Data looks fine in console. (when i change result to results) but i dont get object but {results: DataSnapshot}

Comment: When i edit it like this: 

firebase.database()
      .ref("testdb")
      .orderByChild("isDonor")
      .equalTo(true)
      .once("value")
      .then((results) => {
        results.forEach((snapshot) => {
          donorsData.push(snapshot.val());
           });
        setData(donorsData);
        console.log(donorsData);

       })

It is working, but still not show anything on ios. Its stuck on Loading. On web is everything ok.

Comment: Now in console (Desktop) i see objects. On IOS Simulator is data empty.